# man string vs man string.h

Tags: linux

`man string` will show ISO C string header.

`man string.h` will show Posix C string header.

similar to `man stdio` vs `man stdio.h`

however, in particular `man string` does not have APIs like `memcpy` etc, it does not reflect what's in /usr/include/string.h(which has memcpy etc)

why is this?

Comment: Man pages vary from distro to distro, so we would have to know what distribution you are using.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux systems, [`man string`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/string.3.html) *doesn’t* document `string.h`, it lists the “string operations”:

> `stpcpy`, `strcasecmp`, `strcat`, `strchr`, `strcmp`, `strcoll`, `strcpy`,
> `strcspn`, `strdup`, `strfry`, `strlen`, `strncat`, `strncmp`, `strncpy`,
> `strncasecmp`, `strpbrk`, `strrchr`, `strsep`, `strspn`, `strstr`, `strtok`,
> `strxfrm`, `index`, `rindex` — string operations

Most of these are defined in `string.h`, a few in `strings.h`. The document isn’t intended as an exhaustive list of all the functions and data structures in `string.h`.

Similarly, [`man stdio`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) technically doesn’t document `stdio.h`, it lists the functions in the stdio library; but in practice that ends up largely being the same.